# How do I use a static library (in my case assimp) without the source files

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries, assimp

I have a libassimp.a file and the header files. How can I use the library?

I'm adding the header files to my project with `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -isystem ${ASSIMP_INCLUDE_DIR}")`. With ASSIMP_INCLUDE_DIR being ../contrib/assimp/include.

Now when I use some class in my main.cpp it gives me errors about undefined references to some funtions, because obviously I don't have the source files.

When I add the libassimp.a to my compile flags I get the following errors when using make:

```
make[3]: *** No rule to make target `../contrib/assimp/lib/libassimp.a',
...
main.cpp:7:32: fatal error: assimp/Importer.hpp: No such file or directory
....
Linking CXX static library libassimp.a
```

I don't understand these messages. Maybe they are there because it's trying to access libassimp.a before it's actually there? Is this some kind of concurrency problem?

Anyways, if I call `make` again then I get different errors, namely a bunch of undefined references to things I am not using, e.g.

```
../contrib/assimp/lib/libassimp.a(AssbinLoader.cpp.o): In function `Assimp::AssbinImporter::InternReadFile(std::string const&, aiScene*, Assimp::IOSystem*)':
AssbinLoader.cpp:(.text+0x2a49): undefined reference to `uncompress'
```

**EDIT:**

I am compiling with CMake like this:

```
target_link_libraries(monoRenderer [some other libraries] ${ASSIMP_STATIC_LIB})
```

`ASSIMP_STATIC_LIB` is the path to libassimp.a.

**EDIT2:**

I reduced my CMake file to this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(monoRenderer)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14")

file(GLOB_RECURSE CXX_SRCS src/*.cpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE C_SRCS src/*.c)
file(GLOB_RECURSE HPP_HDRS src/*.hpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE H_HDRS src/*.h)
set(SRCS "${C_SRCS};${CXX_SRCS}")
set(HDRS "${H_HDRS};${HPP_HDRS}")

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/contrib/assimp/include)

add_executable(monoRenderer ${SRCS} ${HDRS})
target_link_libraries(monoRenderer ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/contrib/assimp/lib/libassimp.a)
```

The header files are in `contrib/assimp/include` and the libassmip.a is in  `contrib/assimp/lib`. It still doesn't work, same errors as before.
My main.cpp looks like this:

```
#include <assimp/Importer.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    Assimp::Importer importer;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**EDIT3:**

I think it has something to do with zlib, since all the errors seem to have that in common I think:

```
undefined reference to `uncompress'
undefined reference to `inflateInit2_'
undefined reference to `inflate'
undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
undefined reference to `inflateReset'
undefined reference to `inflateSetDictionary'
undefined reference to `get_crc_table'
undefined reference to `crc32'
```

Comment: Can you post how you compile your project?

Comment: You have missed the `cmake` tag.

Comment: Using `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` directly probably not what you want. You should use `include_directories` to add the include dir. Are you using `${ASSIMP_INCLUDE_DIR}` somewhere else?

Comment: I changed it to `include_directories` but I'm getting the same errors, must be something else. Yes, I am using it for my `ExternalProject_Add_Step` to move the headers to the right folder.

Comment: @mistapink: I added a minimal working example of my main.cpp and CMake file.

Comment: Shouldn't your `main.cpp` use `#include <assimp/include/Importer.hpp>`?

Comment: @RjOllos: No, then it would say `fatal error: assimp/include/Importer.hpp: No such file or directory`

Comment: But does `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/contrib/assimp/include` have a `assimp` sub directory? You may need to add dependencies of assimp as well to link with your project, here zlib.

Comment: @mistapink: Yes, adding -lz worked with my reduced example! However my original project now has another error with gtest that I hadn't have before. I don't think the errors are related to, it says that the configure step for 'gtest' doesn't work because a CMake file is missing.

Comment: Break it down to an MVCE and open a new question.

Comment: @mistapink: Yes, I will, just found out that it doesn't even work now if I just compile assimp. But adding `-lz` worked to resolve the errors in this question, if you want you can put it in an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @mistapink: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35219589/building-assimp-3-2-does-not-work-anymore) is my followup question, if you're interested. Should be reproducible this time! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated yourself you are encountering problems with zlib. You have to add all dependencies from your static library yourself, e.g.:

```
target_link_libraries(monoRenderer z)
```

Since you stated that your header are located in `contrib/assimp/include` you might want to change your include in `main.cpp` to

```
#include <Importer.hpp>
```