# Building assimp 3.2 does not work anymore

Tags: cmake, makefile, googletest, assimp

I can't build assimp 3.2 anymore. Yesterday it worked but today it doesn't.

I am downloading assimp from [here](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/releases/tag/v3.2/). Then I'm doing `cmake CMakeLists.txt -G 'Unix Makefiles'` and `make` as described in their `INSTALL` file. However when doing `make` I get the following error:

```
[ 84%] Performing configure step for 'gtest'
CMake Error at /home/gartenriese/Documents/assimp/assimp-3.2/test/gtest/src/gtest-stamp/gtest-configure.cmake:16 (message):
  Command failed: 1

   '/usr/bin/cmake' '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=' '-Dgtest_force_shared_crt=ON' '-Dgtest_disable_pthreads:BOOL=OFF' '-GUnix Makefiles' '/home/gartenriese/Documents/assimp/assimp-3.2/test/gtest/src/gtest'

  See also

    /home/gartenriese/Documents/assimp/assimp-3.2/test/gtest/src/gtest-stamp/gtest-configure-*.log



make[2]: *** [test/gtest/src/gtest-stamp/gtest-configure] Error 1
```

`gtest-configure-out.log` is empty, however `gtest-configure-err.log` says the following:

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/gartenriese/Documents/assimp/assimp-3.2/test/gtest/src/gtest" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
```

Any ideas? It worked yesterday and I did *not* change anything on my system globally.

**EDIT:**

I can build it with the option `-DASSIMP_BUILD_TESTS=OFF` added to the cmake command. However this is just a workaround and does not explain the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because project assimp used incorrect link to gtest repository

Currently [cmake-modules/AddGTest.cmake](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/master/cmake-modules/AddGTest.cmake) used [link](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/googletest) to chromium repository which is deprecated and all code removed from it.

From README.md

```
This mirror has been deprecated. 
The actual repository has moved to https://github.com/google/googletest/
```

So you should update link in AddGTest.cmake to point into Github repository.

**UPDATE:**

Pull request was already merged into assimp's master branch. So use it instead of repository from comments.

Comment: If I do that it completes 'gtest', however afterwards it says `fatal error: gtest/gtest.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: @gartenriese here the change I've made to use new repo https://github.com/snikulov/google-test-examples/commit/d4a3d02c27073405bb7e53fe6ad553e406928af6

Comment: I added your changes and also changed `link_directories(${binary_dir)` to `link_directories(${GTEST_LIBS_DIR})`. However now it says `No rule to make target `test/gtest/src/gtest-build/libgtest.a', needed by `bin/unit'.  Stop.`

Comment: BTW, I kept the ExternalProject name `gtest` for convenience.

Comment: @gartenriese Could you please check you build on https://github.com/snikulov/assimp branch gtest_upd ?

Comment: Yes, that works. You should make a pull request. Thanks!

Comment: @SergeiNikulov could you share that repo again, it's now showing 404 on your link and I have this issue too. Thanks -Edit, nevermind, I got the changes from the link in your answer.

Comment: @Dover8 It because it was already merged into upstream repository with following commit https://github.com/assimp/assimp/commit/982d597acf3a8ae8ed6da21e83d930b547d2893a . So just use assimp master branch. It was already fixed here.